# Azure DMS Error(PostgreSQL to Azure PostgreSQL : Not able to select the tables of source database while performing DMS

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, database-migration, dms

I am migrating data from PostgreSQL to Azure PostgreSQL and I am unable to select any table while performing Azure DMS

Comment: Please give us more details about the problem, such as error message, your steps and  screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is completed. Actually, the target database should have the tables otherwise migration is not possible